# Populating a list view using an array adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm trying to populate a list using an array adapter. I have 3 classes, Bike, CustomAdapter and UseCustomAdapter. I have an example and I've been through it comparing it to mine and can't seem to figure out why it just doesn't run! Just say's it's stopped working every time I try and load it up. Here's the code:

Bike.java

```
package com.example.tasktwo;

public class Bike {

    private String title;
    private String imageName;


    //Constructor
    Bike (String title,  String imageName) {
        this.title= title;
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setImage(String imageName){
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }   

    public String getBikeTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getBikeImageName(){
        return imageName;
    }
}
```

CustomerAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bike>  {
    private final Context context;
    //List of Walk Objects
    private ArrayList<Bike> bikes;

    //Receives the context and the list of walk objects
    public CustomAdapter  (Context context, ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        super(context, R.layout.bike_view, bikes);
        this.context = context; 
        this.bikes = bikes;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Bike bike = bikes.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bike_view, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bike_names);
        textView.setText(bike.getBikeTitle());      
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bike_image);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        int imageId = res.getIdentifier(bike.getBikeImageName(), "drawable", "com.example.tasktwo");
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

UseCustomerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.tasktwo;

public class UseCustomAdapter extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        bikes.add(new Bike("Honda", "honda"));
        bikes.add(new Bike("Suzuki", "suzuki"));
        bikes.add(new Bike("Kawasaki", "kawasaki"));
        bikes.add(new Bike("KTM", "ktm"));
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, bikes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Bike b = bikes.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(this,"You selected the " + b.getBikeTitle()
                        + "Motocross Bike",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): Process: com.example.tasktwo, PID: 1009
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tasktwo/com.example.tasktwo.BikeList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.example.tasktwo.BikeList.onCreate(BikeList.java:20)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     ... 11 more
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tasktwo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".BikeList"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post LogCat / Stack trace.

Comment: Is that okay? Never posted logcat before - sorry

Comment: Check your BikeList.java line 20, What is on this line??
--- Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-10 14:34:53.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): at com.example.tasktwo.BikeList.onCreate(BikeList.java:20)

Comment: Hmm - I deleted BikeList.java as I was told it wasn't needed, how come it's finding errors for the class even though i've deleted it?

Comment: Clean your project once. and check if working.

Comment: Cleaned and still saying 
03-10 15:22:06.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 15:22:06.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1782): Process: com.example.tasktwo, PID: 1782
03-10 15:22:06.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1782): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tasktwo/com.example.tasktwo.BikeList}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tasktwo.BikeList" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tasktwo-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.tasktwo-2, /system/lib]]

Comment: I cant find anywhere in the code where it mentions that class either, I thought deleting it wouldn't cause any problems

Comment: Somewhere I think there is BikeList.java, search for it in your project and delete it. Maybe you're importing another project that contains BikeList, and therefore the code references BikeList instead of Bike.

Comment: @Saffa Please post your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Hi @TheOriginalAndroid & abforce, I have added my AndroidManifest.xml and I've found BikeList in there, however I'm not sure how to rectify it? I deleted the class but I must have named something else BikeList. How would you go about fixing this?

Comment: @abforce - wouldn't let me tag you in the message above

Comment: @Saffa, I posted an answer based on your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your responses, I think this is the solution.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
</activity>
```

Note the name is **MainActivity** which is default. This name depends on the name of your main Activity class. So set it to whatever the class name is.
The issue with Android Studio or Eclipse is that when you start changing project names, all the references are not changed properly.

Comment: Thankyou! UseCustomAdapter is the activity!

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful, you can click on the up arrow icon too. I like your question since I did not know of this issue. And perhaps I can help someone else with the same problem.